# I tried converting my python file to exe file, but the exe file won't open

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I have written a program and would like to export it to an .exe file. I used `cx-freeze`, and, although it normally works, it hasn't worked with this code. The converted .exe file won't open.

```
from ctypes import windll
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from pynput.mouse import Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time
import webbrowser
from tkinter import messagebox
import keyboard
#from tkinter import *

def start():
    window2.destroy()
    hdc = windll.user32.GetDC(0)
    mouse = Controller()
    webbrowser.open('https://games.htmlgames.com/WhackEmAll/')
    time.sleep(5)
    def wait_until(x, y, operation, colour, wait):
        hdc = windll.user32.GetDC(0)
        if operation == '!':
            while windll.gdi32.GetPixel(hdc, x, y) != colour:
                time.sleep(wait)
        if operation == '=':
            while windll.gdi32.GetPixel(hdc, x, y) == colour:
                time.sleep(wait)

    def click_on(x, y, wait):
        mouse.position = (x, y)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(wait)

    wait_until(802, 444, '!', 16777215, 1)

    click_on(802, 444, 1)

    click_on(684, 632, 1)

    click_on(847, 539, 0)

    start = time.time()
    end = start + 60


    x_pos = [455, 725, 885, 455, 670, 885, 455, 670, 885,]
    y_pos = [315, 315, 315, 495, 495, 495, 675, 675, 675]
    colour_mole = [15263718, 10277608]

    time.sleep(1)

    window = tk.Tk()
    def exit(event):
        window.destroy()
        stop = 2
    window.bind("<Escape>", exit)
    window.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    window.title("AI")
    label0 = tk.Label(window, text="Welcome to my Whac-A-Mole AI!", font=("Helvetica 10 bold"), fg = "blue")
    label1 = ttk.Label(window, text="Hold ESC for 1 sec to exit the AI", font=("Helvetica 10 bold"))
    label0.grid(row=0, column=0)
    label1.grid(row=1, column=0)


    while time.time() <= end and not keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
        window.update_idletasks()
        window.update()
        for x in x_pos:
            for y in y_pos:
                if windll.gdi32.GetPixel(hdc, x, y) in colour_mole:
                    mouse.position = (x, y)
                    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    window.destroy()
    window.mainloop()

window2 = tk.Tk()
window2.title("AI")
window2.resizable(0,0)
t2_label0 = tk.Label(window2, text="Welcome to my Whac-A-Mole AI!", font=("Helvetica 10 bold"), fg = "blue")
t2_label1 = ttk.Label(window2, text=" Press Start to begin the AI")
t2_label2 = ttk.Label(window2, text=" You will only be able to stop the program once the game has begun")
t2_label3 = tk.Label(window2, text="WARNING: THIS PROGRAM WILL CONTROL YOUR MOUSE", fg = "red")
t2_label0.grid(row=0, column=0)
t2_button = ttk.Button(window2, text = "Start", command = start)
t2_label3.grid(row = 4, column=0)
t2_button.grid(row = 3, column=0)
t2_label1.grid(row=1, column=0)
t2_label2.grid(row = 2, column=0)
window2.attributes("-topmost", True)


window2.mainloop
```

I do not know what has happened. I even tried with `exemaker` and `pyinstaller` but these didn't work either. Could someone please tell me what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Although it will convert, the exe file won't open

Comment: What's the error you've getting when you've running exe?

Answer (score 1):

you should try using [Auto Py To Exe](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/auto-py-to-exe/), i use that tool for all my tkinter projects, and it has worked perfectly!

Comment: this should rather be a comment, and until you are allowed to do so, please stick to posting answers that help the OP

Comment: @RichBanana, I installed it, but it only has a html page

Comment: @RAW_tech Yeah, you use the html page to make the exe

Comment: @RAW_tech Here is a tutorial on how to use Auto Py To Exe if you want: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZSZHmWSOeM&t=)